# Top 5 most clicked URL SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

Table1:

```
Clientid, CampaignName(email label),Segments(High spender, low spender etc)
```

```
Table 1     
Campaign1   Cell01  Client1
Campaign1   Cell02  Client1
Campaign1   Cell03  Client2
Campaign1   Cell02  Client2
Campaign1   Cell03  Client3
```

Table2:

```
Clientid, URL, CampaignName(email label)
```

```
Table 2     
        URL
Campaign1   Client1 youtubelink
Campaign1   Client1 homepage
Campaign1   Client2 youtubelink2
Campaign1   Client2 youtubelink2
Campaign1   Client3 youtubelink3
```

I want to write a code for which URL was clicked most(top 5 most clicked URLs) for each campaign/email over a period of time( I will create a month by month bar chart). I understand this can be achieved using RANK(). Can someone please help or guide me, Thanks heaps.

Note: Each combination of Campaign and segment can have multiple URLs linked.for example: one email(combination of Campaign+Segment) can have multiple URLs and we can click anywhere. I need to record where is the user clicking most.
Need to see most effective link to conclude wether or not our campaigns are working.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?